# Website alignment differing on mobile when deployed

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I'm running into an issue where the text alignment and overlay image are not showing up on this website on mobile. (everything works and looks perfect for all resolutions when using Chrome dev tools, but found out that does not fully emulate an actual mobile view)

I saw someone recommend adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`, but that didn't fix it.

Here are the CSS styles I have for the text and image. ('first' is "Sample", 'last' is "TEXT', 'abstract' is the star image)

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.first {
  line-height: 0.59;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 0.3em;
  border: none;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.last {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  margin-top: -3px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.abstract {
  position: absolute;
  width: 30vw;
  top: -14vw;
  right: 10vw;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

The attached images of what shows up. The image with the '1' label (to the right of "Sample) is what I am trying to do, and the image with the '2' label is what shows up. Any help is appreciated!

[Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/yzB3xAf)

Comment: few suggestions you can try:
1. Used Media Queries @media (max-width: 767px) { }
2. use (%) or the rem unit instead of vw and em  for responsiveness